# Creating a new columns based on values of other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, eval

I would like to create a columns which checks if there exists a specific value in a column list.
This value is Y=1. 
What I tried already is

```
mask = df[col_list] ==1
```

Which gives me the output for every column individually. But I want a evaluater which checks for every line in the col_list if there exists a Y=1 and if there exists one gives out True.
What I would like to have:

```
df['evaluator'] = df[col_list].eval(col_list[line = i] == 1 for one column then return True)
```

Is this possible with eval? How should I build the expression?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
df[col_list].eq(1).any(axis=1)
```